# Testing background-image of a css class using Angular Karma

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I have a div, for which I have created a a class lets say `.open-banner` which is something like :

```
<div class="banner-section open-banner"
     [ngClass]="{'banner-closed' : !isOpen}">
</div>
```

with css classes as :

```
.open-banner {
    background-image: url("/assets/images/image1.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


.banner-closed {
    background-image: url("/assets/images/image2.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

In my spec file, I am trying to access the url of image and test if it loads proper image using:

```
fit('should set banner background',()=>{
    component.isOpen = true;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const ele = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.open-banner')).nativeElement;
    console.log(ele.style.backgroundImage)
});
```

But it's coming as empty. What am I doing wrong ?

Actually, doing `console.log(ele.style)` gives all empty values as below:

> LOG: CSSStyleDeclaration{alignContent: '', alignItems: '', alignSelf: '', alignmentBaseline: '', all: '', animation: '', animationDelay: '', animationDirection: '', animationDuration: '', animationFillMode: '', animationIterationCount: '', animationName: '', animationPlayState: '', animationTimingFunction: '', backfaceVisibility: '', background: '', backgroundAttachment: '', backgroundBlendMode: '', backgroundClip: '', backgroundColor: '', backgroundImage: '', backgroundOrigin: '', backgroundPosition: '', backgroundPositionX: '', backgroundPositionY: '', backgroundRepeat: '', backgroundRepeatX: '', backgroundRepeatY: '', backgroundSize: '', baselineShift: '', blockSize: '', border: '', borderBlockEnd: '', borderBlockEndColor: '', borderBlockEndStyle: '', borderBlockEndWidth: '', borderBlockStart: '', borderBlockStartColor: '', borderBlockStartStyle: '', ......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you try to access `ele.style`, it only gives the styles that are defined on the element through the style attribute. To get the styles defined through classes and all, you can make use of the `getComputedStyle` method - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

So this should get you the style value you are looking for

```
console.log(getComputedStyle(ele).backgroundImage);
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much !